# Auto Layout with adaptive Layout editor

Tags: swift, autolayout

As you can see in the photo, the objects on the iPhone6 are at the bottom, but they are not at the bottom of the iPhone XS Max.

How do I place these objects automatically for each phone?

I have shared my code to edit the `labelcircleBox`. For example, how do I perform Auto Layout on this label?

[iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O4xL.png)

[iPhone XS max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RKya.png)

I think we can solve this problem with Width-Regular, Height-Compact

```
view.addSubview(labelcircleBox)
labelcircleBox = "Cihazı Güncellemek için Tıklayınız"

// labelcircleBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 630).isActive = true
labelcircleBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
// labelcircleBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
labelcircleBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

let horConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelcircleBox, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let verConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelcircleBox, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY,  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 245.0)

view.addConstraints([horConstraint, verConstraint])
```

> How can do I automatically edit layout according to iPhone phone
>   models?

Comment: In this code you appear to be constraining your `labelcircleBox` to the centre of `view` but there is no indication of what `view` actually is.  You don't need to take note of the devices themselves you need to constrain your views to the bottom of the safe area (or bottom layout margin).

Answer (score 0):

> How can do I automatically edit layout according to iPhone phone models?

You don't. You make *one* layout that works for *all* phone models. That is what auto layout *is*.

> How do I place these objects automatically for each phone?

By placing them in relation to the boundaries of the phone. For example, if you want something to appear "at the bottom" for all phones, constrain its bottom to the bottom of the safe area.

Comment: although I do not receive reference with bottom, the top side is reference.